# How to make "completion buffer" as single-column

Tags: completion

Is there any way that the`completion buffer` shows every item in a single line. By default it arranges the items in several columns. (Try to do `M-x f <TAB>` to see what I mean).

In general what are the variables which control the appearance of this buffer?

Comment: There are a number of packages available that provide 'enhanced' completion which you might be interested in: http://oremacs.com/swiper/ and https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/ are two of the more popular

Comment: @Tyler These projects are indeed useful and practical, but keep in mind that they are not able to override the `*Completions*` buffer and do not always provide their own alternative to functions which use it.

Comment: @Basil You might be correct in so far as these packages don't do anything to `*Completions*`, but they do reduce or eliminate the situations where it shows up.I have `M-x` bound to `counsel-M-x`, and when I enter `M-x f` I am presented with a single column of completion candidates, as OP would like. I'm no longer bothered by the layout of `*Completions*`, since I don't see it. This indirectly resolves the issue, which is why I offered it as a comment and not a solution.

Comment: @Tyler You're absolutely right - I only meant to clarify this (as you say, infrequently occurring) limitation, namely that `ivy` and `helm` are not able to intercept those few functions which don't use the common minibuffer and in-buffer completion interfaces of `completing-read` and `completion-in-region`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude way to do that is:

```
(defun my-completion--insert-strings (strings)
  (dolist (string strings)
    (insert (propertize string 'mouse-face 'highlight) "\n")))
(advice-add 'completion--insert-strings
            :override #'my-completion--insert-strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Emacs offers no control over this.  In general, there are no "*variables which control the appearance of this buffer*".

But if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then this is easy, using option [`icicle-candidate-width-factor`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-candidate-width-factor).

You can also [change this on the fly](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display#ChangeCompletionsSpacingOnTheFly) anytime, during completion. (One size does not fit all when it comes to completion candidates.)

See [Completions Display](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display) for more information.